# Can YARD be used to declare @return type as type of one of the arguments?

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard

What I want to do is basically:

```rb
# @param [class] cls
# @return [instanceof(cls)]
def get(cls)
  # Imagine this is method and object has property @instances = {}
  if !@instances.keys.include?(cls)
    @instances[cls] = cls.new()
  end

  @instances[cls]
end
```

It can be very handy for the service container pattern, when using it like

```rb
service = container.get(MyClass) # language server (e.g. solargraph) will see service variable as of type MyClass
```

Is it possible with YARD?

UPDATE:

fixed example of function, it did return simply cls.new() in the past

Comment: It is still rertuning an object of type Cls, so it doesn't really change anything.

Answer (score 0):

### Just Declare a Type or Duck-Type in Your Return Tag

YARD already does this. What you're likely misunderstanding is how YARD uses brackets to document the [type](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#return) of the return value. You're also welcome to add free-form descriptions if you really feel it's necessary. However, pragmatically speaking, you're really just expecting your *cls* argument to respond to #new, so I'd rewrite it (and make it slightly more idiomatic) like so:

```rb
# @param klass [#new] a Class or other object that
#   can +#respond_to? :new+
# @return [Class] an instantiated instance of +klass+
def get klass
  klass.new
end
```

If you want to be more explicit, you could change the type in the @param tag to:

```rb
# @param klass [Class, #new]
```

so that it's clear that you're expecting a Class, but will also accept a duck-typed object that responds to #new. Since the method is exactly one line long, I think it's pretty unambiguous either way, especially with the description. Your taste and code style may vary, though.

In either case, the square brackets should [declare one or more types](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#declaring-types), even if they're duck-types. So, yes, you can do what you want.

### Ruby 3.2 Note

Unless something changes in the next month, in Ruby 3.2.0 you can make this even shorter with an "endless" method definition. For example, using ruby-3.2.0-preview2:

```rb
# @param klass [Class, #new]
# @return [Class] instance of +klass+
def get(klass) = klass.new
```

Whether or not you like the new syntax, it certainly works. For example:

```rb
obj = get Object
obj.instance_of? Object
#=> true
```

This isn't better or worse than the old syntax, but I do think it lets you tighten up the code and the documentation while increasing clarity. Again, your mileage may vary.

Comment: I'm very thankful for you writing the answer, but I suspect I did misinform you by my post. What I mean by def get(cls); return cls.new() end; - I mean that method/function DOES NOT return explicitly cls.new() right away but it searches for it in some hash or something, meaning that code tree analyser is kinda confused and won't be able to guess that method/function returns something .new()

I can't write the specific Class in Yard doc string above the method/function, but I'm searching the way to write something like

```ruby
# @param [Object] cls
# @return [instance_of(cls)]
```

Comment: @idchlife You don't. Whatever *cls* is, it's type is Cls. If that isn't short for Class then you might consider refactoring to a more informative name, but `# @return [Cls] some convoluted way of returning an instance of Cls` would still be right. You could also use `@see` to point to the Class or method that implements your logic. The point is that YARD is just documentation. It's up to you to explain why you're doing what you're doing is a way that helps read the code; YARD doesn't really care beyond treating certain documentation tokens in certain ways for formatting and linking.

Comment: @todd-a-jacobs thank you for clarification! I think the task is beyond the power of Yard and I should look into rbs/rbi generics or something. In the question I wondered if Yard is capable of replacing type Class in doc with any type provided as argument and also returning the same type, but instance. Example code I tried: https://pastebin.com/wfuAYihc

Yard requires explicitly defined type or duck-type and won't try to move the provided type into the return section. Yes, duck-typing helps with basically "any" type and solargraph guessing for completion helpers, but not for return. Thanks!